# Use javascript/jquery to modify edit-body field when editing a drupal node

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I'm trying to manipulate the edit-body field with javascript just before I save a node in Drupal and can't seem to modify the content with consistent results.  I used the following example code:

```
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('edit-body');
htmlstr = "<p>Hello World</p>";
oEditor.SetData(htmlstr);
```

And sometimes my changes are going through and other times my content is duplicated.

I tried disabling the wysiwyg editor so I can see the raw html code and tried alter the edit-body field with Javascript and that didn't do anything.  The edit-body field remained the same.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: I've managed to find a work around by disabling the fckeditor for my node and using setting the edit-body before it submits the page.  Sounds straight forward but for some reason it wasn't quite working before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider doing this in a validation or submit handler instead. That way you wont be dependent on the user's browser.

You can do this by using `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: That's actually a good point, should've spotted that earlier. Cheers!